# Accessing text files out of python directory

Tags: python, operating-system, copy, move, shutil

I am doing a project using python in which I got stuck at a point where I want to access some text files which are saved outside the project directory.

The path where my text files are saved:

```
C:\Users\saqibshakeel035\Desktop\Scientific Project Lithim battery project\text_file_r_w
```

The path of my python project:

```
C:\Users\saqibshakeel035\PycharmProjects\Tutorial_1
```

I want to open/read my text files *(external > not included in python project folder)*

I already know the Reading/writing etc etc within the same folder where the python project `.py` file is present but struggling with the different paths.

I tried:

```
import os
from os import path
print("Your cunrrent directory is : %s"  %path.curdir)
strpath = r"C:\Users\saqibshakeel035\Desktop\Scientific Project Lithim battery project\text_file_r_w"
print("Your current directory is %s: " %path.dirname(strpath))
print("Your current directory is : %s"  %path.abspath(strpath))
```

This works fine and it shows my abspath where my text files are stored but when I try to read it with the following command

```
f = open("file1.txt","r")
```

It gives error that no such directory or file found

Comment: Why don't you use the absolute path?

Comment: For example how?

Comment: Use `with open(strpath+"file1.txt","r") as f:`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try `f = open("C:/text/to/path/file1.txt","r")` or the code @Jaba has mention. Either works fine

Comment: are you doing f = open("C:/Users/saqibshakeel035/Desktop/Scientific_Project_Lithim_battery_project/text_file_r_w/file1.txt", "r") ? Also your path Scientifici Project Lithim battery project does not have an underscore so it may also affect how the file path is trying to read it.

Comment: Thanks. Following code works fine. There was a problem of forward backward slash in the path.

 import os from os import path strpath = r"C:/Users/saqibshakeel035/Desktop/SP/text_file_r_w" print("Your current directory is : %s" %path.abspath(strpath)) f = open("C:/Users/saqibshakeel035/Desktop/SP/text_file_r_w/file_" + limit1 + ".txt", "r") print(f.read())

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the full path to "file1.txt" in the open function.

```
f = open("Full_path_to_file1.txt", "r")
```

Another option is to change the current directory,
os.chdir(path)

Comment: Thanks.
Following code works fine. There was a problem of forward backward slash in the path.
import os
from os import path

strpath = r"C:/Users/saqibshakeel035/Desktop/SP/text_file_r_w"
print("Your current directory is : %s"  %path.abspath(strpath))
f = open("C:/Users/saqibshakeel035/Desktop/SP/text_file_r_w/file_" + limit1 + ".txt", "r")
print(f.read())